# Nginx proxy_pass after rewrite loses URI segments

Tags: nginx

I am trying to rewrite a url then proxy_pass the result to another server. Here is my setup:

```
server {
    rewrite ^/foo(.*)$ $1 last;
    location /bar {
        proxy_pass http://myserver/;
    }
}
```

So when I make a GET request for `/foo/bar/dir/file.txt` I expect the first rewrite to remove `/foo`, the location block to catch the result of the rewrite, then proxy_pass to `http://myserver:8000/dir/file.txt` because the trailing slash on the proxy_pass will strip off `/bar`.

This is what I expect however when I have the trailing slash then `/dir/file.txt` is lost in the proxy_pass, and the request is only made to `http://mysever/` root URI. I confirmed when I take off the slash then `/bar/dir/file.txt` is indeed the request the upstream server.

Is there some extra step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird, I expect the same behaviour from this config as you. What if you strip the `/bar` prefix inside the `location` block? Maybe this workaround would work?

```
    location /bar {
        rewrite ^/bar(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://myserver;
    }
```

Comment: Yes this does work. Wish I didn't need that extra rewrite though. I'll probably just leave that out and deal with the url at the next server.